# Rewriting url using mod-rewrite and apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add some rewriting on my site, but it seems to not work, I'm using apache and .htaccess.

The code in my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?os_framework/?$ /os_framework/index.php?module=home [L,NC,QSA,PT]
```

This should send http://localhost/os_framework/ to http://localhost/os_framework/index.php?module=home
But it seems not to.

Any help would be appreciated.

In advance, thanks

Edit: Fixed the above, shouldn't have the `os_framework/` in the search pattern, however now i cant get this one to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.[^/]*)/?$ /os_framework/index.php?module=$1 [L,NC,QSA,PT]
```

And what is wrong with

```
RewriteRule ^(.[^/]*)/?$ /os_framework/index.php?module=$1 [L,NC,QSA,PT]
```

Why does that throw a error 500? it should work

Comment: Why are you using the `?s` on the search pattern...have you tried it without?

Comment: the `?s` tells that the identifier before it can be optional, so it would react on both `os_framework` and `os_framework/`

Comment: What happens exactly? 404 not found error or what? Anyway for debugging purposes you can try `RewriteRule ^os_framework/?$ os_framework/index.php?module=home [R]`, so you'll see if and what Apache is rewriting your URL to.

Comment: But why would you put a `?` immediately following the **leading** slash?  The path would always be `/os_framework`, right?

Comment: It just loads the default index file with no arguments, and `[R]` doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^os_framework/?$ os_framework/index.php?module=home [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled yes, and no there are no error messages :/